# How come the messages only print client side on the gui?

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, customtkinter

I've written code for a chat room and the basic GUI is complete, however, if two clients have connected and they write a message it only appears client side while also appearing on the client GUI that sent the message. So how come that is? I have it so the server echoes the message back to the clients and it's obviously receiving the messages but not sending them back.

Server code:

```
# imports
import socket
import threading


# Servers address and port (inputted)
def set_address_and_port():
    IP = input("Please input your IP: ")
    port = int(input("Please input your port: "))
    global SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT
    SERVER_ADDRESS = IP
    SERVER_PORT = port
    return SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT


# client handler that should echo the clients message back
def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not message:
                break
            print(f"Received from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}: {message}")

            # Echo the received message back to the client
            client_socket.broadcast(message.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            break

    client_socket.close()


# Maintain a list of connected client sockets
connected_clients = []


# starts the server again
def start_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server is listening on {SERVER_ADDRESS}:{SERVER_PORT}")

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Client connected: {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
        connected_clients.append(client_socket)

        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
        client_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_address_and_port()
    start_server()
```

GUI CODE:

```
# imports
import customtkinter as ctk
import socket
import threading
import select


# server  address and port
SERVER_ADDRESS = '192.168.15.7'
SERVER_PORT = 1234
username = input("Enter your username: ")

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
client_socket.setblocking(False)

# GUI WINDOW size and appearence
chat = ctk.CTk()
chat.geometry('900x600')
ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')

# Press enter to send message
def handle_return_key(event):
    send_message()

# send message function used in the button
def send_message():
    message = message_entry.get()
    message_entry.delete(0, len(message))

    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

# columns and row configuration
chat.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
chat.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
chat.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

chat.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
chat.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
chat.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
chat.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
chat.rowconfigure(4, weight=0)

# message entry box
message_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=chat, placeholder_text="Message Here...", width=300)
message_entry.bind(sequence = '<Return>', command=handle_return_key)

message_entry.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky="ew", pady=20)

# send message button
send_button = ctk.CTkButton(chat, text="send", command=send_message, hover=True, width=100)
send_button.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")

# textbox, currently not working for some reason, wont print message into it,
textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(chat)
textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='nsew')
textbox.insert("end", f"Client Connected: ({username}) {SERVER_ADDRESS}, {SERVER_PORT}\n")



# insert code for receiving new network messagesg
def received_messages():
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive the echoed message from the server
            received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            client_socket.close()

            # Display the received message in the GUI's textbox
            textbox.configure(state="normal", text_color="black")
            textbox.insert("end", f"Received: {received_message}\n")
            textbox.configure(state="disabled", text_color="black")  # configure textbox to be read-only
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break

send_receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=received_messages)
send_receive_thread.start()

# updates chat
while True:
    chat.update_idletasks()
    chat.update()
    try:
        received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if received_message:
            textbox.configure(state="normal")
            textbox.insert("end", f"{username}: {received_message}\n")
            textbox.configure(state="disabled")

    except Exception as e:
        pass
        #print(e)
        #break
# chat.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling broadcast on client_socket (which would explain why they receive the echo), perhaps what you meant to do is loop through connected_clients and broadcast(sendto) everyone that is not client_address?

Comment: could you show me how to do that, I'm still stuck.

Comment: there were a few problems so I went ahead and made the changes and gave an explanation.  let me know if I made it too confusing or whatnot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the initial problem described:

> if two clients have connected and they write a message it only appears client side while also appearing on the client GUI that sent the message.

I think there is a type-o and it should read

> "...it only appears server side while also appearing on the client GUI that sent the message."

This would mean the 2 possible problems:

1. when a client sends a message the server receives the msg, then the server sends the message back to the sender and not to all the other clients connected.
2. when a client sends a message to the server, the GUI adds the message to the senders screen then sends the msg to the server which gets the message but never broadcasts it to anyone

Looking at the GUI code, when the user enters text and hits enter or clicks the send button then the GUI sends the msg to the server.  The only time the GUI is updated is if it receives a message from the server.  Knowing this we can rule out #2, which tells us the problem lies in the server code.

we know the issue involves sending, so looking at the server code there is only one place where messages are sent, and that is in the `handle_client()` function.  The comment in this function shows us the line that is being used to 'echo' the message back to the sender, confirming the last sentence in the info OP gave, however that sentence also says:

> "...I have it so the server echoes the message back to the clients"

However, that line uses `.broadcast()` which only sends the message back to the original sender instead of sending it to every connected client.  I think this is the actual problem OP is looking for help with.

The sockets (client/GUI side and server side) are initialized with socoption socket.SOCK_STREAM (TCP) but if this was SOCK_DGRAM (UDP) instead, then `.broadcast()` would send to a specific port on all hosts in the segment but for TCP it only sends to one.  So, we need to rework that 1 line for TCP.  Thankfully, OP has already created a list to track connected clients which we can use.  The trick here though is that the main thread has the connected_clients list and every client thread will need access to this list, creating a race condition.

The following updates were made to the server:

1. import Lock so we can prevent any race-conditions introduced with multi-threading where 2 or more threads try to read or modify a
   shared variable at the same time resulting in, at best, an error or warning and at worst undefined behavior (sometimes it might work with expected results, sometimes with unexpected results, and if you're lucky one of those might cause a runtime error)
2. the connected_clients list was made into a list[(ipaddress, socket)]. this makes it easy to prevent duplicates and prevent the server from sending the message back to the sender (the server should pass along the message to everybody that is not the sender... the senders GUI should update the text area with the message after they send or hit enter).  This is important if file/picture sending or something is implemented as the server shouldn't waste resources returning things back to the sender who already has access to it
3. updated the `.broadcast()` line.  We use the map() function to iterate over every tuple in the connected_clients list.  Map takes a function and a list as arguments.  Here we use a lambda function:
   `lambda user_addy, user_sock: user_sock.broadcast(message.encode('utf-8'))`
   since we know map() iterates over every item and we know each item is a tuple, we can unpack the tuple for the lambda function to use, we name these `user_addy` and `user_sock`.  After unpacking the tuple we define the function we want the lambda to use on every list item, so we use `user_sock.broadcast(message.encode('uft-8'))` as the function.  we only want to do this for every client that did not send the message so we add a conditional to the function we told the lambda to use to look like this:
   `user_sock.broadcast(message.encode('uft-8')) if user_addy != client_address[0]`
   and now we have a lambda function that will call .broadcast() on the tuple if the tuple does not have the same address as the client that sent the message.
4. we need to remove the client from the connected_clients list, whenever they disconnect, otherwise the server will continue to try and send messages to a client that will always timeout.
5. anytime the client thread accesses the shared variable connected_clients we need to use Lock() so if another thread needs this variable it will wait until the current thread is done using it and removes the lock
6. in start_server() we add a check to see if the newly connected client already has a socket associated with their address.  if they don't, we add them to connected_clients and spin up a thread for them.  if they do already have a socket, we want to get the current one associated with their address and call close() on it, then we want to replace it with the new one we got from the .accept() call.  this means every address can only have 1 socket associated with it and if they try to connect again, it will be replaced with the new socket so the server will always send messages to the last socket the client used to connect with.

Here's the updated server code with the above changes made:

```
from threading import Lock

# this lets us 'lock' the use of a list to only 1 thread at a time to prevent a race condition
data_lock = Lock()
connected_clients: list[(str, socket)] = []

def close_client(client_socket, client_address):
    client_socket.close()
    with data_lock:
        connected_clients.remove((client_address[0], client_socket))

# client handler that should echo the clients message back
def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    while True:
        try:
            # map iterates over 'shared memory' so 
            with data_lock:
                socket_list = [x[1] for x in connected_clients]
            ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([client_socket], socket_list, [], 1)
            size_message = 0
            for s in ready_to_read:
                size_message = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not size_message:
                break
            bytes_recved = 0
            chunks = []
            #get the full message
            while bytes_recved < int(size_message):
                chunk = ready_to_read[0].recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                #if the socket closed
                if chunk == "":
                    close_client(client_socket, client_address)
                    #raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                    #if we break instead of raise an error we can still send the partial message to all the clients
                    break
                chunks.append(chunk)
                bytes_recved += len(chunk)
             
            message = ''.join(chunks)
            print(f"Received from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}: {message}")

            #send full message to each connected client
            for sock in ready_to_write:
                totalsent = 0
                #1st, send the size of the message
                if len(str(bytes_recved).encode('utf-8')) == sock.send(str(bytes_recved).encode('utf-8'))
                    while totalsent < bytes_recved:
                        sent = sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
                        if sent == 0
                            close_client(client_socket, client_address)
                            #no need to raise error, we can remove the client from connected_clients and continue sending to the next socket in the list
                            break
                        totalsent += sent

        except:
            break

    close_client(client_socket, client_address)


# starts the server again
def start_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server is listening on {SERVER_ADDRESS}:{SERVER_PORT}")

    while True:
      ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([server_socket], [], [], 1)
      client_socket = None
      client_address = []
      for s in ready_to_read:
          client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
      print(f"Client connected: {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
      
      #create a dict from the list of tuples: {'address': socket} then we can use `in` to see if we already created a socket for this address
      if client_address[0] not in dict(connect_clients):
          with data_lock:             
              connected_clients.append((client_address[0],client_socket))

          client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
          client_thread.start()
      #if we already have a socket for this address, close the current one and replace it with the new one in the list
      else:
          with data_lock:
              d = dict(connected_clients)
              addy = client_address[0]
              d[addy].close()              
              d[addy] = client_socket
              connected_clients = list(d)
```

Now the server will operate as expected.  Unfortunately, the answer alone to get the server to send messages to every connected client would have lead to more problems and broken code.  In the interest of thoroughly answering the intended question and prevent OP from having half an answer and needing to post a 2nd or follow up question I've lightly touched on 'race conditions', however I would strongly suggest further researching into this term if OP or anyone is interested in getting into multi-threading.

UPDATE:
Error(35) is due to the non-blocking TCP socket.  If recv() doesn't receive anything it raises an error.  send() also works a bit differently with non-blocking sockets in that it will not wait the function to finish sending data... in fact, it stuffs as much into the buffer as possible then it returns, so if you try and send more data while the buffer is full, or before the server can clear the buffer, you can overflow the buffer and get a socket.err..

GUI CODE:

```
# imports
import customtkinter as ctk
import socket
import threading
import select
from threading import Lock

# this lets us 'lock' the use of a list to only 1 thread at a time to prevent a race condition
data_lock = Lock()

# server  address and port
SERVER_ADDRESS = '192.168.15.7'
SERVER_PORT = 1234
username = input("Enter your username: ")

# GUI WINDOW size and appearence
chat = ctk.CTk()
chat.geometry('900x600')
ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')

# Connect socket
def get_client_socket(address, port, blocking = False, socket_type = socket.AF_INET, socket_mode = socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket_type, socket_mode)
    client_socket.connect((address, port))
    client.setblocking(False)
    return client_socket

#client_socket
client_scoket = get_client_socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT)

#Update Chat
def update_chat(received_message = "")
    # updates chat
    #while True:
    try:
        #if a thread using a lock calls update_chat() after the main thread/loop, we want the main one to finish up then let the thread have access.  
        with data_lock:
            chat.update_idletasks()
            chat.update()
        #release the chat var, we don't need it now
        #start new lock
        with data_lock:
            if received_message:
                textbox.configure(state="normal")
                textbox.insert("end", f"{username}: {received_message}\n")
                textbox.configure(state="disabled")
    except Exception as e:
        pass

# Press enter to send message
def handle_return_key(event):
    send_message()

# send message function used in the button
def send_message():
    message = message_entry.get()
    message_entry.delete(0, len(message))
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([], [client_socket], [], 1)
    for s in ready_to_write:
        #get the size of the message we're sending
        send_size = len(message.encode('utf-8'))
        #1st, send the size of the message and ensure all bytes were sent
        if len(str(send_size)) == s.send(str(send_size)).encode('utf-8')
        #2nd, send the message
        #keep sending until the whole message has been sent
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < send_size    
            sent = s.send(message.encode('utf-8')[totalsent:])
            if sent == 0:
                #we can wait 1 sec then try and reconnect
                sleep(1)
                try:
                    s = get_client_socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT)
                    #we call break instead and give up trying to get the rest of the message
                    continue
                except:
                    raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            totalsent += sent

# insert code for receiving new network messagesg
def received_messages():
while True:
    try:
        ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([client_socket], [], [], 1)
        # Receive the echoed message from the server
        for s in ready_to_read:
            size_message= s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            bytes_recved = 0
            chunks = []
            #get the full message
            while bytes_recved < int(size_message):
                chunk = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if chunk == "":
                    #we can wait 1 sec then try and reconnect
                    sleep(1)
                    try:
                        s = get_client_socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT)
                        #we call break instead and give up trying to get the rest of the message
                        continue
                    except:
                        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                chunks.append(chunk)
                bytes_recved += len(chunk)
             
            received_message = ''.join(chunks)
            #update the chat with the new message
            with data_lock:
                update_chat(received_message)

        #if we close the client_socket here it won't be able to receive any more messages
        #client_socket.close()

        # Display the received message in the GUI's textbox
        textbox.configure(state="normal", text_color="black")
        textbox.insert("end", f"Received: {received_message}\n")
        textbox.configure(state="disabled", text_color="black")  # configure textbox to be read-only
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

while True:
    update_chat()
```

Comment: since the wrong question was asked but the problem was understood I went ahead and added the thought process used to find and fix the problem and since the answer alone would have introduced worse problems (race condition) I included where and how this can happen as well as including the code to prevent it.

Comment: @Bodabear, I am getting an error (35) which means something is open right? why is that happening, do I use select(), if so, how?

Comment: @AlexanderWaller I updated the GUI and server code to use select.  I also changed the receive and sending for both the GUI and server so they can send messages of any size.  I just did a simple impl for this, anytime a message is sent there are 2 messages sent: 1st the size of the message we're sending is sent.  after that the actual message is sent.  this lets the receiving end know how long of a message to expect allowing it to know when it's done reading.  in non-blocking send and recv both only signal when the socket is closed but not when they are done w the task

Comment: @AlexanderWaller i changed the GUI code a bit, i put the code to update chat in a function `update_chat(received_message = "").  the main loop calls this function instead.   inside `received_messages():` it also calls update_chat with the data_lock.  I'm not sure if it'll work correctly like this or not, I'm not able to test it for you right now but I thought I'd add it anyway to show how you don't need to close client_socket and how update chat doesn't need to handle receiving messages.  oh and send_message will try and reconnect if the socket closes for whatever reason